# Powershell to match lines in one file to part of a line in another.

Tags: powershell

So I have two files, one with a list of numbers and a description, the other with just a list of numbers.

Eg:
File 1 contains:

```
10001 Screw  
23456 Bolt
```

File2 contains:

```
10001  
23456  
23456
```

What I'm trying to do is for every time the number appears in File2 it adds the description to it or outputs the number and description to a new file.
So result would look like:

```
10001 Screw  
23456 Bolt  
23456 Bolt
```

These are just small samples but the actual files are many thousands of lines.

This is what I've come up with but it's not quite right.

```
$file1 = "C:\pstest\file1.txt"
$file2 = "C:\pstest\file2.txt"

Get-Content $file2 | Foreach-Object -process {Get-Content $file1 | Where-Object  $_ -contains $file2 | write-host $_ }
```

OR

```
$file1 = "C:\pstest\file1.txt"
$file2 = "C:\pstest\file2.txt"
$file3 = "C:\pstest\file3.txt"

Get-Content $file2

foreach ($line in $file2){
    Get-Content $file1 | Where-Object $_ -contains $line | out-file $file3 
}
```

Comment: Should have mentioned the two are tab separated.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a good case to use a hashtable. First, load up `file1`, iterate over it and store the lines as key-value pairs. Then you can just lookup the value from the hash in `file2` and get the corresponding item:

```powershell
$file1 = Get-Content "C:\pstest\file1.txt"
$file2 = Get-Content "C:\pstest\file2.txt"
$file3 = "C:\pstest\file3.txt"
$h = @{}

foreach($line in $file1) {
  if ($line -match '(\d+)\s+(.*)') {
    $h[$matches[1]] = $matches[2]
  }
}

foreach($line in $file2) {
  $line = $line.trim() 
  write-output "$line $($h[$line])" | Tee-Object $file3 -Append
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you explain the matching criteria `'(\d+)\s+(.*)'`   ? Would it matter that some of the numbers are like `100-015` (with a dash) or `100-015-PL` with letters and that the two are tab separated? Also this code didn't like the -Append giving error `Tee-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Append'.`

Comment: The match is one or more numbers followed by one or more spaces followed by anything else. As you've said the values are tab separated, you could change it to `(.*?)\t(.*)` instead. You can remove `Tee-Object`, I only put it there so it would write to screen and to file. You could just pipe to `Out-File` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the hash table, but for that many lines I'd do it like this:

```
$HT = @{}

Get-Content $file1 |
foreach {
 $HT[$_.split("`t",2)[0]] = $_.split("`t",2)[1]
 }

Get-Content $file2 -ReadCount 5000 |
foreach {
 foreach ($part in $_)
  { 
    "$part $($HT[$part])" | 
    Add-Content $file3 
  }
 }
```

That lets you work with 5000 lines at a time in memory, cutting down the number of disk reads required to chew through the input file.

Comment: This is an interesting point... Why does reading 5000 lines at a time cut down on disk reads? I thought `Get-Content` loads the entire file into memory? Does it actually hold a reference and do something smart in the background?

Comment: Get-Content, by default reads one line at a time (ReadCount 1).  ReadCount 0 will load the entire file into memory, but then memory management eats into your performance.  For small records a ReadCount of 3-5000 should be about all one process can deal with at a time without having to do a lot of memory management to make room for it. Using a ReadCount of 5000 will make Get-Content start reading and handing you arrays of 5000 lines at a time, then you just have to iterate through each array as it comes down the pipeline.

Comment: I think a hash table is the way to go. I started to look at that but wasn't to familiar with it so didn't pursue. This code gave me just Chinese character output in file3 ??? perhaps is to do with the input. As below some of the numbers contain dashes and letters and the part and description are tab separated.

Comment: I modified the script to expect tab-separated part and description, and keep the description together if it contains spaces.   It's best if you can describe the data early in the process, and preferably give examples that include the possible formats it may be in.